# Azure Terraform - how to add encryption values to VMs

Tags: azure, encryption, terraform-provider-azure

What is Terraform equivalent to

az vm encryption enable --name  --resource-group  --volume-type OS --aad-client-id  --aad-client-secret  --disk-encryption-keyvault https:///secrets//

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [**`Repository`**](https://github.com/interrupt-software/az-vm-disk-encryption)

> We configure the Azure Key Vault service for Server-side encryption
> (SSE) for the Azure Managed Disk in this config. The procedured can be
> procured using the Terraform provider [`azurerm_disk_encryption_set.`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/disk_encryption_set.html)

```
 resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "example" {
  name                = "des"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  key_vault_key_id    = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that equivalent to: az vm encryption enable --name  --resource-group  --volume-type OS --aad-client-id  --aad-client-secret  --disk-encryption-keyvault https:///secrets// ?

Comment: How to connect it with my VM (created with azurerm_virtual_machine)?